# Filtering rows in view

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datagridview

I'm new in database and C# but i would like to learn it. So sorry if i ask noby question but i couldn't find answer anywhere I've tried ( I have found a lot answers with SQL databases but not with access databases )

I want to make simple program with contacts to workers:

- there will be Name of Company and then all necessarily info to contact the dealer of this company.
- The idea is to allow user to search company and then by button in `gridview` -> open all contacts which i have to this company like phones to dealers, boss, fax, email etc. )

I've already loaded data to my `gridview` by this code:

```
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\Programy\Baza Danych Kontakty\Dane.accdb";
connect.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connect;
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Firma";

OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = reader[2].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = reader[0].ToString();
}
connect.Close();
```

but I have really big problem to filter records.. This database should have few hundredths of records with way more contacts so filtering it from hand aren't good idea I guess. And also I would like to filter data by typing in `textbox`..

example: i start typing : B ( it shows me every Company name which have B in her name ) then O ( it shows companies with BO ) + E ( BOE ) + I ( BOEI )  +N ( BOEIN ) and +G ... it should filter in real time ( without button "search").

Like i said i found many answers for SQL data users, but any for access data users.. And better for me to stay in access since I must make school project in this data.

I hope I am clear enough with my needs, and hope that someone know how to help me.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: hello. Welcome!. if you saw a lot of examples on c# and SQL server, then use one of them for your access db. both are going to be exactly same, just that replace all SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlReader with OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, OleDbReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this code. Manish Mishra gave good idea :)

So filtering with using oledb and access database which work for me:
(Note: im just starting so probably there is bether way to do it, anyway it works)

`

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\Programy\Baza Danych Kontakty\Dane.accdb";
        connect.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT FirmaKod,FirmaNazwa FROM Firma";


        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        datatable.Load(reader);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv = datatable.DefaultView;
        connect.Close();

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "FirmaNazwa like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            if (textBox1.Text == "") dv.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data of a grid after binding it, regardless of the datasource from which it is binded.

Try this:

```
DataView dv = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "FromColumn like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Doing something like above in textChange event of the textbox will omit the use of button to filter results!